# Are these steps valid (interior and exterior definite integrals)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given
$$A(x)=\int^x_{X_0} \int^{\tau}_{t_0}\frac{dh}{dX}\:dt \:dX$$

and knowing that $X$ and $t$ are functions of each other, the question is, are the following steps valid?  If not, please indicate where I go wrong, why it is an illegal move, and if there is another way to get to the last step.

$$A(\tau)=\int^{\tau(x)}_{t_0(X_0)} \int^{x(\tau)}_{X_0(t_0)}\frac{dh}{dX}\:dX \:dt$$

$$A(\tau)=\int^{\tau(x)}_{t_0(X_0)} h \:dt$$

$$\frac{dA}{d \tau}=h(\tau)$$

Answer (score 1):

A lot of what you've written makes no sense. You can't have $X$ and $t$ as functions of each other. You are integrating over a region in $(X,t)$ space: $R=\{(X,t): X_0\le X\le x, t_0\le t\le \tau(X)\}$. One of its boundary curves is given by $t = \tau(X)$; assuming this is a one-to-one function, with inverse $X = \chi(t)$, you could then write
$$A(x) = \int_{t_0}^{\tau(x)} \int_{X_0}^{\chi(t)} \frac{dh}{dX}\,dX\,dt =
\int_{t_0}^{\tau(x)} \big(h(\chi(t))-h(X_0)\big)dt \,.$$
This is still a function of $x$.

Your writing $A(\tau)$ is wrong, and certainly your final derivative is incorrect.

Comment: $X$ is parameterized by $t$.  $X=X(t)$  Doesn't that mean $X$ and $t$ are "functions of each other"?

Comment: Why do you have to write $h$ as function of both $\chi(t)$ and $t$?  Why isn't it just $h(\chi(t))$?

Comment: In your equation (far RHS), the upper bound on the integral is also the variable of integration since $t=\tau(x)$.  Isn't that a no-no?

Comment: Ah, my fault. I was thinking $h=h(X,t)$, but then you wouldnhave needed a partial derivative. I'll edit. Try a concrete example. Take the region given by $R=\{(X,t): 1\le X\le x, 2\le t\le X^2+1\}$. And only on the boundary curve, once again, are $X$ and $t$ related.